# Loopback 4: Filter option

Tags: node.js, loopback4

Loopback 4 allows to use an automatic/default filter that is really helpfull. My problem is that I want to use it in a customize way an I am not able.

Usual:

```
return this.customerRepository.findById(idCustomer, filter);
```

My Case:

I don´t want to attack the "id" of the model, I want to attack another field. I have tried serveral things, but as a resume an example:

```
return this.customerRepository.findOne({where: { idUser: currentUserProfile.id }}, filter));
```

If I do that, the filter stop working. Any idea of how to mix a field in the model different than the id and the filter of loopback 4?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

@Jota what do you mean the filter stopped working? You have the correct idea about the approach. to search by a specific field just put it in the where clause as such:

```
this.customerRepository.findOne({ where: { <field_name>: <value_to_search> } })
```

e.g.

```
const filter = {
   where: {
     email: 'hello@world.com'
   }
};

const result = await this.customerRepository.findOne(filter);
```